# if else statement in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to do following: I have this in my htaccess

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site-staging\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://new_site-staging.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

So, I'm removing "www" and redirecting to "new_site-staging.com" everything and if there is some specific page user entered I'm redirecting there.
My question is, can I make some kind of if/else statement:

```
if (URL == "site2014.com") {
   RewriteRule ^ https://site2014.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
} else {
  RewriteRule ^ https://new_site-staging.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
}
```

So, if it's site2014 then redirect to that one and if it's not redirect everything to new_site-staging.com.
Is this possible through htaccess?

Comment: Can you place your complete .htaccess in question?

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just create the same set of rules for site2014.com under the RewriteRule for the first domain? And just general redirect after everything, then.

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.site2014\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://site2014.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^new_site-staging\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://new_site-staging.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Do you mean like this:
"
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site-staging\.com$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site2014.com\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://site2014%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^ https://new_site-staging.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
"

Comment: It always redirect me to first rule

Comment: Still nothing, tried many combinations but always I'm redirected to first rule.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your rules like this:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site2014\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^site2014\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://new_site-staging.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```